# EhCache 3 Configuration not working with simple configuration of springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, ehcache-3

Below is my Simple Config Class

```
package com.mcd.restaurantmanager.product.config;

import org.springframework.cache.annotation.EnableCaching;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@EnableCaching
@Configuration
public class CacheConfig {
}
```

Below is my ehcache.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns="http://www.ehcache.org/v3"
        xmlns:jsr107="http://www.ehcache.org/v3/jsr107"
        xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.ehcache.org/v3 http://www.ehcache.org/schema/ehcache-core-3.0.xsd
            http://www.ehcache.org/v3/jsr107 http://www.ehcache.org/schema/ehcache-107-ext-3.0.xsd">

    <cache alias="hierarchyLevelByRestaurantGroupId">
        <key-type>java.math.BigDecimal</key-type>
        <value-type>java.lang.String</value-type>
        <expiry>
            <ttl unit="seconds">30</ttl>
        </expiry>

        <listeners>
            <listener>
                <class>com.mcd.restaurantmanager.product.service.CustomCacheEventLogger</class>
                <event-firing-mode>ASYNCHRONOUS</event-firing-mode>
                <event-ordering-mode>UNORDERED</event-ordering-mode>
                <events-to-fire-on>CREATED</events-to-fire-on>
                <events-to-fire-on>EXPIRED</events-to-fire-on>
            </listener>
        </listeners>

        <resources>
            <heap unit="entries">2</heap>
            <offheap unit="MB">10</offheap>
        </resources>
    </cache>

    <cache-template name="default">
        <expiry>
            <ttl unit="seconds">30</ttl>
        </expiry>
        <listeners>
            <listener>
                <class>guru.springframework.ehcache.config.CacheLogger</class>
                <event-firing-mode>ASYNCHRONOUS</event-firing-mode>
                <event-ordering-mode>UNORDERED</event-ordering-mode>
                <events-to-fire-on>CREATED</events-to-fire-on>
                <events-to-fire-on>EXPIRED</events-to-fire-on>
                <events-to-fire-on>EVICTED</events-to-fire-on>
            </listener>
        </listeners>
        <resources>
            <heap>1000</heap>
            <offheap unit="MB">10</offheap>
            <disk persistent="true" unit="MB">20</disk>
        </resources>
    </cache-template>

</config>
```

Below is how I am using caching with methods

```
  @Cacheable(value = "id", key = "#restaurantGroupId")
    public String getLevel(BigDecimal id, String somRandom) {
        return getGroups(somRandom).stream()
                .filter(restaurantGroup -> restaurantGroup.getId().equals(id))
                .map(restaurantGroup -> restaurantGroup.getLevel().getValue())
                .findFirst()
                .orElse(null);
    }
```

This is my listener

```
package com.mcd.restaurantmanager.product.service;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.ehcache.event.CacheEvent;
import org.ehcache.event.CacheEventListener;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Slf4j
@Service
public class CustomCacheEventLogger implements CacheEventListener<Object, Object> {
    @Override
    public void onEvent(CacheEvent<?, ?> event) {
        log.info("Cache event = {}, Key = {},  Old value = {}, New value = {}",
                event.getType(),
                event.getKey(),
                event.getOldValue(),
                event.getNewValue());
    }
}
```

I am not sure if I missed something, but I am getting below error

**A component required a bean of type 'org.springframework.cache.CacheManager' that could not be found.**

Please let me know what I am missing, I am using ehcache 3.

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution? I am using SpringBoot 3 and JDK17 and org.springframework.cache.ehcache package exists no more.